# use external file with variables

Tags: bash

The following is iptable save file, which I modified by setting some variables like you see below.

```
-A OUTPUT -o $EXTIF -s $UNIVERSE -d $INTNET -j REJECT
```

I also have a bash script which is defining this variables and should call iptables-restore with the save file above.

```
#!/bin/sh

EXTIF="eth0"
INTIF="eth1"

INTIP="192.168.0.1/32"
EXTIP=$(/sbin/ip addr show dev "$EXTIF" | perl -lne 'if(/inet (\S+)/){print$1;last}');

UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"
INTNET="192.168.0.1/24"
```

Now I need to use

```
/sbin/iptables-restore <the content of iptables save file>
```

in bash script and somehow insert the text file on top to this script, so the variables will be initialized. Is there any way to do that?

UPDATE: even tried this

```
/sbin/iptables-restore -v <<-EOF;

$(</etc/test.txt)

EOF
```

Comment: Reposted [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/247013/how-to-read-data-from-file-containing-variables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
while read line; do eval "echo ${line}"; done < iptables.save.file | /sbin/iptables-restore -v
```

or more nicely formatted:

```
while read line
  do eval "echo ${line}"
done < iptables.save.file | /sbin/iptables-restore -v
```

The eval of a string forces the variable expansion stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Use . (dot) char to include one shell script to another:

```
  #!/bin/sh
  . /path/to/another/script
```

Comment: The first line of your example is confusing.

Comment: That probably should be `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: the text within script is not another script but just data, containing $variables.

Answer (score 1):

In your shell script:

```
. /path/to/variable-definitions
/sbin/iptables-restore < $(eval echo "$(</path/to/template-file)")
```

or possibly

```
/sbin/iptables-restore < <(eval echo "$(</path/to/template-file)")
```

Comment: doesn not really work, it is still waiting for user input from stdin

Comment: @Michael: Can you edit your question to show more specifically what it is you're trying to do and what the steps to achieve it are? There seems to be something missing in your question.

Comment: @Dennis: actually it's quite simple what I want. Just to read data and put into certain position. Guess I will have to use EOF markers...

Comment: @Michael: I still don't see how the first line (the one that starts with `-A`) comes into play. Normally, you'd use `iptables-restore < saved-file`.

Comment: @Dennis: but in saved-file you can not specify shell variables... I've modified the saved-file and put some variables wihch I needed.

Comment: @Dennis: first one gives "No such file error", of course the file is there. Second one "Syntax error: redirection unexpected".

Comment: @Michael: You have your question tagged `[bash]` so I used Bash syntax. The problem is that your script is not using Bash since your shebang says `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash`. If you change it then my second example should work.

Comment: @Dennis: the second example now with bash reads the whole file as a single line, thus giving an error that on second line I should have `COMMIT`, whereas my file consists of many lines including `COMMIT`.

Comment: @Michael: I'm sorry, there should be quotes around the part that does the `echo`. See my edit.

Comment: @Dennis: sorry to tell but this doesn't help either. It is trying to run each line as a command and at the end also gives error that I should have `COMMIT`.